# LFTP mget ignoring case

Tags: pattern-matching, case-insensitive, lftp

In LFTP, is there a way to mget files matching a pattern, say `*.csv` but want to match any case variation, whether `*.CSV` or `*.cSv`, etc. This is not restricted to matching `*.csv` but to any other possible string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently the only way is this one:

```
*.[cC][sS][vV]
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you have any plans to implement this functionality down the road?